# Swift how to multiply value of quantity put in textfield with UIStepper

Tags: swift, xcode6

I working on a Swift app that uses a UIStepper , for user to enter a quantity into textField, how can I take the quantity and multiply by value stored in var?

```
Here is what I have so far


  var value1 = 4 // value to multiply //
  @IBOutlet weak var oneValue     : UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var oneClicker: UIStepper!
  @IBOutlet weak var totalTextField: UITextField! // show total value1 * oneValue //

   @IBAction func oneClicker(sender: UIStepper) {
    // puts quantity into oneValue textField //
    self.oneValue.text = Int(sender.value).description
            }

   @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {

   // just can't figure out method? //

}
 //Thanks for help//
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {
    println("\(calculate(self.oneValue.text.toInt()!)")
}

func calculate(value: Int) -> Float {
        return Float(value * value1)
}
```

There you go.

Comment: Thanks for help , I tried this it did not work for me for some reason

Comment: I get an error that says methods declared in IBAction must return void not float Thanks for helping me

Comment: Thanks again for help Oscar, I put in exactly how you have it here got an error on println , then app crashed when I tried?

Comment: Hi Oscar Im using Xcode 6.5, maybe it's the way i laid out whole file or something